# Permanent employee leaving immedialty without any notice

Tags: united-kingdom, resignation

An year into a job role, are there any sort of complications to immediately leaving a permanent position, when in contract employee is required to give 3 months notice ?

Comment: This is going to depend a lot on your contract. Also, why do you want to leave without giving notice?

Answer (score 8):

Obviously yes - you will have as much trouble as the employer wants to cause you. You would be in breach of your contract; if your employer thinks that causes them damages, they can sue you or your next employer. That’s what contracts are there for.

This is something that you should really negotiate. OTOH if you need to leave because of a sick family member, or to serve a jail sentence, your employer may be understanding.

Comment: I agree the OP should talk with his employer.

Comment: _they can sue ... your next employer_ The next employer is not a party to the prior employment contract, and not bound by its terms. Such an action would probably fail before even a court hearing, or if not costs and other losses would likely be awarded against the plaintiff (original company). Reasons to do this are to cause the employee as much trouble as possible, or frighten the new company into not employing them. +1 for negotiation, although "force majeure" would probably apply in the case of jail sentence.

Answer (score 4):

You'll be in breach of contract. It all depends on what sort of monetary/criminal/civil implications there are but nobody here would know as you're the only one with the actual contract. I suggest you read it, and possibly consult a lawyer on what your options are. It's probably best to simply give the notice.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your contract really, and even then it would be best to consult a lawyer. If you've undergone any training or courses you may be required to reimburse the cost of the training.